# SEARCH ALL with a key PIC XX

Tags: cobol, mainframe

I'm using `SERACH ALL` on a table with a key with a type `PIC X(02)`

Bellow is my table declaration

```
01  WS-VAL    PIC X(02). 
01  WS-TABLE.
        03  WS-TABLE-LINE OCCURS 400 TIMES
                                 ASCENDING KEY IS TAB-KEY
                                 INDEXED BY IND-TAB.
            05  TAB-KEY      PIC X(02).
            05  TAB-LIB      PIC X(15).
```

Bellow how i use SEARCH ALL

```
SET IND-TAB     TO 1
SEARCH ALL WS-TABLE-LINE
   AT END 
      DISPLAY 'NOT FOUND'
   WHEN TAB-KEY (IND-TAB) = VAL
      DISPLAY 'FOUND'
END-SEARCH
```

`VAL` exists on the keys of the table but the message `'NOT FOUND'` is usually displayed

Answer (score 6):

You're use of `SEARCH` is nearly correct (set the index on plain `SEARCH` as this operates from the current index value, but not on `SEARCH ALL` which sets the index itself), but the table likely isn't.

`SEARCH ALL` goes over the complete table with a binary search. We don't know so we have to guess:

- you have much less than 400 entries in, possibly even less than 200
- the data is not initialized, so contains either garbage or low-value (common on mainframes) or spaces (common on PC, would also be the case on mainframe after `INITIALIZE WS-TABLE`)

Then your `SEARCH` will start at around entry 201, finds a key that is less than what you search for, therefore goes up to 301, still finds a key that is less, then goes to 351, 375, ... and ends at position 400 with only keys seen that are less than your current one.

The *dirty* way is to ensure that all keys are pre-set for example with `HIGH-VALUE`.
The *right* way is to add something like `DEPENDING ON WS-TAB-ENTRIES` to your `OCCURS` clause and set this correct; in this case the search only happens binary in the range of the *current* setup maximum, not the absolute maximum any more.

Note: as `SEARCH ALL` does a binary lookup, the data in the table **must be sorted per your definition** - if this isn't the case then do a `SORT WS-TABLE` once (again: after setting the `OCCURS DEPENDING ON` value or pre-set all keys to `HIGH-VALUE` (or `ZZZ` if you like that more) - otherwise the "empty" entries will be sorted up front [that alone would make your `SEARCH ALL` work correctly, but waste computing power]).

Comment: @AhmedSEDDIK - `OCCURS 0 TO 400 DEPENDING ON WS-TAB-ENTRIES` where `WS-TAB-ENTRIES` contains the number of active entries in the table.